Error when trying to use Copy Database Wizard on Microsoft SSMS. No Fixes Found
I am attempting to copy a database from one server to another. Initially, I was having a problem with permissions which I managed to find a solution to, but now I am running into a new problem. Every time I try to run the Copy Database Wizard on any server to another, I am getting the same error,

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This happens when the Wizard tries to perform the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.CopyFile(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, Boolean overwriteOnExist).
I am beyond confused as to why it is getting this error since I have double checked my source file several times to make sure it was the correct path. I even made an empty copy of the database on the destination server to see if for some reason it was failing due to their being no destination file. However, this does not make any sense either since the Wizard should be creating the file. Everywhere I search for anyone having a similar problem, but it appears that I am the only one somehow. I thought it might have been a problem with the Version differences, but according to Microsoft, there should be no issue moving from an old version to a new version. If anyone has any kind of solution, please let me know.
I tried doing both the Detach and Attach and the SQL Management Object methods, but neither of them worked. I tried it with no existing Database on the destination, and with the same existing Database by overwriting it. Also, I tried doing the same with two servers that are the same version, but got the same error

Why not just take a backup and restore it on another server

I'm trying to use the Copy Database wizard to create a differently named copy of the database on the same server, and I get exactly the same error.
